# Sweave (using R Studio) with AEA class

Tags: fonts, errors, sweave

Apologies for the newbie question!

I've been having some problems trying to get a minimal working example using Sweave with a the AEA document class.  My minimal example works as a `.tex` file, but the `.rnw` file encounters an error (which I've included below).  Here is the code I'm using:

```
\documentclass[AEJ]{AEA}
\begin{document}
Hello World!
\end{document}
```

As I said, I've been able to compile this when it's saved as a `.tex` file -- I've managed to save the `AEA.cls` (and `aea.bst`) files in the same directory as this script, which seems to work.  However, when I save the same script as a swerve (`.rnw`) file, I get the following error:

```
Font T1/cmr/m/n/10.95=dcr10 at 11.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found
```

I tried (as well) compiling the `.tex` file which was created when I tried to compile the `.rnw` file, but ended up with the same error.

I gather that the problem has something to do with the file path to one of the fonts, but beyond that I'm a bit confused.

Any help on this much appreciated!